# Store array from firebase database

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

l am trying to build a project using Angular and angularfire. My project is about drawing polygons using leaflet map, then pushing coordinates of a polygon to a database. I have successfully pushed an array to the database, but I have a problem to retrieve coordinates from database.

Database Structure :

```
{
  "Locations" : {
    "-M0M9kqEbE0FVMzIZAg0" : {
      "text" : [ [ {
        "lat" : 35.97800618085566,
        "lng" : 42.03369140625001
      }, {
        "lat" : 33.88865750124075,
        "lng" : 41.46240234375001
      } ] ]
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to store array above in class ts not in html.

My code :

```
    export class WeatherNowComponent {

      itemsRef: AngularFireList<any>;
      items: Observable<any[]>;

      coords :any
      constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {

        this.itemsRef = this.db.list('Locations')
        // Use snapshotChanges().map() to store the key
        this.items = this.itemsRef.snapshotChanges().pipe(
          map(changes => 
            changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }))
          )
        );


        this.db.list('Locations').snapshotChanges().subscribe((markers: any) => {

          console.log(markers)
          markers.forEach(singlemarker => {
            console.log(singlemarker)

   // ADD COORDS to MAP POLYGON
    var polygon = L.polygon([singlemarker.text.lat,singlemarker.text.lng], {color: 'red'}).addTo(this.map);
          });
        });

        console.log(this.items)
      }



    }
```

So I have only key array in console log without rest of array objects.

[image]

Comment: `"Locations" : {` should be `"Locations" : [{`?

Answer (score 0):

If you calling a spread operator on purpose because it is an array try assigning it to a property value in the object literal definition.

```
{ key: c.payload.key, values: ...c.payload.val() }
```

Edit: Based on your comment I would still say still just assign the array of coordinates (lat/lng property pairs objects) to the values property to iterate over later. I assume the .val() method must return the array of those values. Otherwise please post what .val() returns.

Also, I noticed something else you should check.

The observable is calling the RxJs pipe() method to map but I didn't notice a subscribe() anywhere. While .pipe() lets you map and filter the callback needs a subscribe.

Edit #2: Based on your second comment below. What you are asking for is still unclear to me. So I will give two more possible answers based on the comment: "okay , my question is how i can get array directly ?"

```
// Possibility #1
// Simplest is to store off the returned data into the coords variable for later processing.
// You can then get the array directly at any later point just by accessing the coords

this.db.list('Locations').snapshotChanges().subscribe((markers: any) => {
    coords = markers;
});

// Possibility #2
// Since the data structure you are using works like a dictionary data structure
// Define some structures to store off the data and get at the array data directly later

// Define this somewhere outside your class
interface ICoordinate {
    lat: string;
    lng: string;
}

// Initialize coordinate dictionary
let coordinates: { [key: string] : ICoordinate[]; } = {};


// Retrieve locations and store off coordinates to get at the array data directly
this.db.list('Locations')
    .snapshotChanges()
    .subscribe((markers: any) => {
        coordinates[markers.key] = ICoordinate[];

        markers.forEach(singlemarker => {
           coordinates[markers.key].push({ lat: singlemarker.text.lat, lng: singlemarker.text.lng });
        });
    });
```

Edit #3: Oh yes, I see. The array needed to be initialized before adding to it.

Updated code. Also, as an additional help to you on future questions it is very helpful if you have a snippet. S.O. question to refer to: [I've been told to create a "runnable" example with "Stack Snippets", how do I do that?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Hopefully that helps.

Happy coding!

Comment: this what i have in console log https://i.ibb.co/TWwy5x0/Capture.png

Comment: Thank you very much for explanation . , but i have error is `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined` under // Retrieve locations and store off coordinates to get at the array data directly